# Permutation and Combination/ Counting

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Q. Our student clubs are being particularly active. The aquatics club in particular is in training for an upcoming competition. For all parts of this question, working is required, including combinatoric/factorial notation as needed as well as final answers.

During training, there are several different types of laps that can be swum:

- freestyle
- arms only freestyle
- one arm only, left then right
- torpedo/kickboard (straight kicking legs only)
- backstroke
- breaststroke

Assume that each type is undertaken at most once in a training session, over contiguous laps (i.e., so once you have completed your freestyle laps, you do not repeat freestyle). The number of laps for each lap type is unimportant, that is, 4 laps of freestyle followed by 2 laps of backstroke is the same as 3 laps of freestyle followed by 4 laps of backstroke.

1. **How many different lap type patterns can be formed from those six types?**
2. **How many patterns contain only three types (e.g., freestyle - arms only - one arm only)?**
3. **How many patterns with at least four different types start with torpedo/kickboard laps?**

b)The club is starting to look at putting together some relay teams. There are 15 swimmers nominating for this opportunity.

1. **If there are three different races, and a team of 5 needs to be nominated for each race, how many different teams can be formed?**
2. **Show a second approach to your answer to i.**

c) One of the club swimmers is putting their training plans together for the competition that is 30 days from now. This swimmer trains no more than once a day. If they have
18 training sessions planned, explain using the counting principles covered in class how this means they will train on consecutive days at least once ahead of the competition.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please [edit] your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.